# Prevent the tag of each tab from shrinking when opening more tabs in Chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, browser

When opening more and more tabs (50+) in Chrome browser, the tag of each tab becomes smaller and smaller, which makes switching between tabs difficult and the name on the tag disappears eventually.

This is not the case in Firefox. So I'm wondering how I can make Chrome behave the same as firefox? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This is actually listed as a feature on the [chromium website](http://www.chromium.org/user-experience/tabs).  It appears there is not currently a solution to this, despite numerous people requesting the feature. The [discussion here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/GNNcVs7MtO0) suggests trying "VerticalTabs" or "TooManyTabs for Chrome".  Also consider adding a star to this issue to [show your support](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=188) for the feature, although that specific issue has been open since 2008 without any change to the browser.  The most recent post by a chromium developer was in May 2014, saying they're working on it.  Finally, I haven't personally tried this, but some users seemed to like this [patch to the source code](https://codereview.chromium.org/3204007/show).

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how it works in Firefox, but in chrome you can hover the mouse over the tabs and scroll through them via the scroll wheel on the mouse.

It's probably not the solution you wanted but it works.

Comment: Works in the same way in Firefox too (at least nowadays).